# 2 Developer Licences -1 iPhone

Tags: iphone, sdk

Can I develop with one iPhone on two developer Licences?

Comment: IANAAG (I Am Not An Apple Guy), but i see no reason that you can't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that works just fine, you'll just need provisioning profiles for the phone from each developer account.

Answer (score 5):

You most definitely can, just provision the phone under the two (or more) development team portals. The different provisioning certificates will all work on your iPhone independently.

Answer (score 1):

The developer licenses are not bound to any particular device except by the provision certificates you create and revoke. You should have no problem working under this configuration (other than extra confusion over multiple developer accounts.)

Answer (score 0):

To expand on fbereto's and gverdouw's answer, if your Apple ID is listed under two iPhone developer accounts you will be presented with a dropdown list on the web site when you log in, asking you to select a team.

Then, as the others have said, just add a provisioning profile from each account to your device. I don't know what the limit is on the number of profiles on a device, but it's more than a handful.